# How to use order_by if it is a t.date or t.decimal field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sunspot, sunspot-rails

How do you order by decimal or date fields?

```
class CreateUserPrices < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def self.up
    create_table :user_prices do |t|
      t.decimal :price, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
      t.date :purchase_date
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I'm trying to sort my user prices to be ordered by price and purchase date.

---

```
searchable do
  text :product_name do
    product.name
  end
  # field for :price?
  # field for :purchase_date?
end
```

What goes in the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure when you add any new code to the `searchable do` block you `rake sunspot:reindex`.

`decimal` fields use **float** and `date` fields use **time**

```
searchable do
  text :product_name do
    product.name
  end
  time :purchase_date
  float :price
end
```